# Context variable cannot be resolved as variable in feature file

Tags: python, bdd

Sometimes when writing scripts in a feature file, a pre-defined context variable can be recognized successfully in step-python-script, but sometimes not. Any clue?
e.g. in env.py, we have method -

```
def before_feature(context, feature):   
   context.url = 'http://test.com'
```

while in feature file:

```
Scenario: send request to service
     `Then send request to "context.url"
```

When debugging, `context.url` cannot be resolved as `http://test.com`, it is the same string `"context.url"` itself...

How does this happen?

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example to your question?

Comment: Update the original post to make it more clearly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, can take re module to match the related variables
https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#step-parameters